# VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products. visual studio 2022

Tags: aws-lambda, visual-studio-2022, aws-toolkit

[image: install log]

Exception:
VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData) at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the extension requires VS 2022 v17.7+, but you have VS 2022 v17.2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

This question is identical to [AWS toolkit not showingup in manage extensions of Visual Studio 2022 (v17.2.22)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77788852/20966954), which explains the cause of the issue, and has a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77803533/20966954