# AWS toolkit not showingup in manage extensions of Visual Studio 2022 (v17.2.22)

Tags: aws-lambda, visual-studio-2022, aws-toolkit

[image: Aws toolkit not showing up in "Manage extensions" of Visual Studio 2022.]

The AWS toolkit is not displayed in "Manage Extensions" of Visual Studio 2022, but it is shown in 2019.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 use separate extensions, you need to install the 2022 version: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2022

Comment: You should also update your Visual Studio 2022 to the latest version (17.8.4 as of writing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the 1.45.0.0 release of the AWS Toolkit, you need to be running version 17.7 or newer of Visual Studio 2022 in order to install this extension.

This is listed in the Toolkit's changelog: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#14500-2023-11-22

See this GitHub issue for the announcement relating to the minimum version bump: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-visual-studio/issues/375

Comment: Thanks, I actually found out on my own but your answer helped me to relate. Thanks for the links shared.